# Convert View block to helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I have an Each/do block in my view currently, but I'd prefer to push this code into a helper, as I need to add a few conditional statements in there so I don't want to clutter up my view. Here is the view I have currently that I have been trying to code as a helper method with no luck so far

```
<% update.voters_who_voted.each do |voter| %>
  <%= link_to profile_path(voter) do %>
    <%= thirty_avatar(voter) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How would this translate into a helper with this name

```
def find_voters_who_voted(update)
  ...
  ...
end
```

I've tried this with no luck

```
def find_voters_who_voted(update)
  update.voters_who_voted.each do |voter|
    link_to profile_path(voter) do
      thirty_avatar(voter)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens, has you an error?

Comment: No error, but it looks as if I inspected the users (it shows all their attributes), like if I did this number `voter.inspect`

Comment: Is thirty_avatar a helper method? Maybe you need to pass voter.name_of_avatar_attribute_name. Something link `thirty_avatar(voter.image)`

Comment: Yea it's a helper method to show either the user's avatar or the default avatar is the user doesn't have one

Comment: Still same outcome. I think the problem comes from the `update.voters_who_voted.each` block

Comment: Which attribute expect to receive your helper? Your complete object? Please paste your result and your avatar helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that all you are doing is displaying the return value of this method. It looks like you are expecting it to act as if it's part of the view, but that's not the way helpers work. Something like this would return the equivalent of your original code block

```
def find_voters_who_voted(update)
  update.voters_who_voted.collect do |voter|
    link_to profile_path(voter) do
      thirty_avatar(voter)
    end
  end.join
end
```

Comment: You're right. That's getting me closer but still wrapping quotes around the output which renders it as text no code

Comment: Adding `.html_safe` to `.join` made it work...Thank you!